# jquery post not work

Tags: jquery, html

I have simple form i want to display search result under div tag so i write some jquery for it but i will not work:

```
<form action="case_databasechange.php" method="post">
    <label>Look in</label>
    <select name="look-in" id="look">
        <!--<option selected hidden disabled value=""></option>-->
        <option value="entry">Entry</option>
        <option value="town">Town</option>
        <option value="Introducer">Introducer</option>
    </select>
    <label>For</label>
    <input name="search-box" type="text" class="wd-500" id="searchv" />
    <!-- id="search-box" changed-->
    <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="search">Search</button>
</form>
```

and I write simple jquery to display  search results:

```
$('#look').change(function () {
    var look = $('#look').val();
});

$('#searchv').keyup(function () {
    var search = $('#searchv').val();
});

$.post("getEntry.php", {
    lookin: look,
    for: search
}, function (data, status) {
    $('#txtHint1').html("data");
});
```

but any result not display under 
`<div id="txtHint1"></div>` tag

Comment: Remove the quotes around `"data"` in `$('#txtHint1').html("data");`. Better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables look and search are locally defined they are limited to the functions.

Try this..

```
$.post("getEntry.php", {
   lookin: $('#look').val(),
    srch: $('#searchv').val()  // do not use for keyword it may not work 
},
 function(data,status){
   $('#txtHint1').html(data); // remove the doube quotes
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the double qoutes from the data. `data` is a variable.

```
$.post("getEntry.php",
{
  lookin: look,
  for: search
},
function(data,status)
{
  $('#txtHint1').html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the double quotes from the `"data"`. data is a variable & You're converting it or using it as String.

Also `for` is a keyword. it may not work, if you want to use it make it string :) .

```
$.post("getEntry.php",
{
  "lookin": look,
  "for": search
},
function(data,status)
{
  $('#txtHint1').html(""+data+"");
});
```

Also your variables `look` and `search` are inside `local function`s So they aren't available to `$.post`, and there is no way for us to detect when `OnWhichEvent?`  `$.post` is invoked?

I'll suggest you to make them `global` and change your code as:

```
var look,search;
$('#look').change(function () {
    look = $('#look').val();
$.post("getEntry.php", {
    "lookin": look,
    "for": search
}, function (data, status) {
    $('#txtHint1').html(data);
});
});

$('#searchv').keyup(function () {
    search = $('#searchv').val();
$.post("getEntry.php", {
    "lookin": look,
    "for": search
}, function (data, status) {
    $('#txtHint1').html(data);
});

});
```

Hope it'll be useful now. :).

Answer (score 1):

Your design is somewhat flawed. You are declaring and initializing local variables within your event handlers but they can't be seen by the global scope -- the values are not available to $.post. Fix it by declaring look and search variables at the top as global variables, then in the handlers just assign values.

```
var look, search; //at the top as globals

look = ....;
search = .....; // in the handlers
```

And the take off the " from data and use 'for': instead of for: